# javascript object destructuring one line with nulls or nullable keys

Tags: javascript, null, destructuring

when destructuring object in js & it has some value which is null then destructuring is failing with error *Cannot read property 'id' of null*

```js
const abc = {a: 1, b: 2, c: null};
let {c = {}, c: {id} = {}} = abc || {};
console.log('c, id', c, id);
```

in case value of a key is null, js throws an exception. we dont know which key is nullable. I want this to be handled in a single line like normal destructuring. is it possible. for this example sake, make into two lines first check if c is null but I want to do it one line.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: What is the goal of this destructuring? Even when `c` has a value, `id` would be `undefined`.

Comment: @Teemu lets say I am getting a response from a service. I dont know its null. so If I destructure this way at run time it will fail. I dont want it to fail also I dont know what key:value can have null. then if I want to destructure in single line what's the way?

Comment: You've put two hours to this, wouldn't it have been much more efficient to just write those two lines instead? Don't minify your developement code, let a minifier do it for you when you move your code to production.

Comment: again you are missing the point. I dont know at run time what could come as null. so for each param I cant split into two lines.

Comment: `const c = abc?.c ?? {}, { id } = c;` is still a single line :-)

Answer (score 1):

The default value in destructuring  will only work for `undefined` properties and not `null`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_values_2)

> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the object is undefined

```js
const abc = {a: 1, b: 2, c: undefined};
let {c = {}, c: {id} = {}} = abc || {};
console.log('c, id', c, id);
```

For `c: null`, you'd have to use:

```
let id = abc.c?.id
```

Comment: yes, I know this. my question is clear. when we dont know that it could be null if we destructure, it will be an issue. so, how can I avoid it while destructuring?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do but, I have got an idea to ***convert nulls to undefined before destructuring*** so that, js will take care of taking the default values.

here is the working code

```js
function removeNulls(obj) {
if (obj === null) {
    return undefined;
}
if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    for (let key in obj) {
        obj[key] = removeNulls(obj[key]);
    }
}
return obj;
}
const abc = {a: 1, b: 2, c: null};
let {c = {}, c: {id, id2} = {}} = removeNulls(abc) || {};
console.log('c, id, id2:', c, id, id2);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Their could be three ways to solve this issue the last one is mine but you can carry with any of the one .

> > making the object destructre in a way that you can add a `or` default case with it to handle the null

```
const { main } =  obj || {}
const { content } =  main || {}
const { title } =  content || { title: 'default title' }
```

> > using a getPropsValue function by passing it by the `.` dot operator like `const title = getPropValue(obj, 'main.content.title')`

```
export const getPropValue = (obj, key) =>
  key.split('.').reduce((o, x) =>
    o == undefined ? o : o[x]
  , obj)
```

> > using a function which make every null key as undefined and you continue use your destructure as you are using earlier with default value .

```
function getNotNull(object) {
    const keys = Object.keys(object);

    keys.forEach((element) => {
      if (object[element] == undefined) {
        object[element] = undefined;
      } else if(!object[element] instanceof Array && typeof object[element] === 'object') {
        return getNotNull(object[element]);
      }
    });

    return object;
  }
```

> The First Two cases can be read in more details from
> https://crunchtech.medium.com/object-destructuring-best-practice-in-javascript-9c8794699a0d